# How to load multiple HashMaps from JSON file using Jackson

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

Basically I am writing a JSON file using

```
private void setupDictionaries() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ArrayList<String> myThing = new ArrayList<String>();
    myThing.add("hi");
    myThing.add(".");

    itemsDict.put("cake", myThing);

    JsonNode childNode1 = mapper.valueToTree(itemsDict);
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("Jan",  childNode1);
    JsonNode childNode2 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("obj2", childNode2);
    JsonNode childNode3 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("obj3", childNode3);
    String jsonString;
    try {
        jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
        writer.writeValue(new File(statsFile), jsonString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this JSON file, I want a similar dictionary generated for all 12 months and load only the one I want to use specifically. However, since these are not simple HashMaps, when I try to load the json file, I get exceptions. Code for loading:

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> loadDict() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = mapper.readValue(new File(statsFile), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>() {});
        //Object map = mapper.readValue(new File(statsFile), new TypeReference<Object>() {});
        System.out.println(map.get("cake");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.util.HashMap: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

My JSON file:

> {
>    "Jan" : {
>      "cake" : [ "hi", "." ]
>    },
>    "obj2" : { },
>    "obj3" : { }
>   }

**EDIT: I think i figured out what causes it**

```
String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(statsFile)));
        System.out.println(input);
        String input1 = "{\r\n  \"Jan\" : {\r\n    \"cake\" : [ \"hi\", \".\" ]\r\n  },\r\n  \"obj2\" : { },\r\n  \"obj3\" : { }\r\n}";
        System.out.println(input1);
```

Running this code, the input is:

> "{\r\n  \"Jan\" : {\r\n    \"cake\" : [ \"hi\", \".\" ]\r\n  },\r\n  >\"obj2\" : { },\r\n  \"obj3\" : { }\r\n}"
>   {
>    "Jan" : {
>      "cake" : [ "hi", "." ]
>    },
>    "obj2" : { },
>    "obj3" : { }
>   }
>   (basically reading from a file, all of it is on a single line, where as having the actual json string in an input string its nice and clean, broken up into multiple lines)
>   Now I only need to figure out how to overcome this...

**SOLVED**
Rather than writing jsonString to the file, I had to write the rootNode

```
private void setupDictionaries() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());

    ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ArrayList<String> myThing = new ArrayList<String>();
    myThing.add("hi");
    myThing.add(".");

    itemsDict.put("cake", myThing);

    JsonNode childNode1 = mapper.valueToTree(itemsDict);
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("Jan",  childNode1);
    JsonNode childNode2 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("obj2", childNode2);
    JsonNode childNode3 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("obj3", childNode3);
    String jsonString;
    try {
        //jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
        System.out.println(rootNode);
        writer.writeValue(new File(statsFile), rootNode);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which i can simply query by

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> loadDict() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        System.out.println("...");
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> map = mapper.readValue(new File(statsFile), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>>() {});
        System.out.println(map.get("Jan").get("cake").get(0));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your `TypeReference`. Your example JSON is something like `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>`

For `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` JSON should be something like

> { "Jan" : [ "hi", "." ] , "obj2" : [ ], "obj3" : [ ] }

**Update:**

Test for your example JSON:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    String input = "{ \"Jan\" : { \"cake\" : [ \"hi\", \".\" ] }, \"obj2\" : { }, \"obj3\" : { } }";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> map = mapper.readValue(input,
            new TypeReference<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>>() {
            });
    System.out.println(map.get("Jan").get("cake").get(0));

}
```

Comment: Changing that line to "HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> map = mapper.readValue(new File(statsFile), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>>() {});" results in the same exception.

Comment: I've added test for your example. Maybe problem is with your file conten, which is not like example above.

Comment: Interesting, this is exactly how I tried testing it, and the content of the file is exact as your example in the input string, but it still throws an error. However, if I also create an input string with the content of the file and just give the .readValue that as an input instead of the file, it works. :(

Comment: "String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(statsFile)));
   HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> map = mapper.readValue(input, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>>() {});" doing this also results in an exception, but if I copy exactly what is in the file I get no exceptions. Wtf?

Comment: I figured it out! I put details in opening.